# Edit width-limited comment blocks faster

Tags: comments, visual-block

Take any long comment in paragraph form:

```
  1 // This is a comment that is really long because it is describing something
  2 // worth being verbose about, possibly at the beginning of the program (like a
  3 // preamble).  It is desirable to keep the width limited to 80-characters,
  4 // conveniently done by typing the whole comment out on one line, selecting
  5 // with SHIFT+V and executing gq.
```

As mentioned, the paragraph is made to span several lines with Vim's `gq` so the width doesn't run off the edge of certain UI's (such as the StackExchange code block).

My question is: **how can the paragraph-comment be edited in Vim?**  I have been:

1. Deleting the comment slashes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>,
2. selecting the text with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>,
3. joining with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>,
4. editing and using `gq` to join them again.

Is there a better (i.e., faster, built-in) way to do this?

Comment: May be, you can use a mapping or a command for that. (Already you are using just 6 keys. If we dont consider shift as a key, its just four keys. I don't think any short cut will exist with three or two keys :D) shall I add a function or command for that?

Comment: `set fo+=cq`, and / or use a smart text formatter such as [Par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/).  See `:h fo-table` for details.

Comment: @SibiCoder, I know Vim is very flexible (and its user base extremely talented) such that a home-brewed macro or function can be put together.  However, I am asking if anyone is familiar with a built-in feature, which I have no way of searching for.

Comment: I'm curious, why you are looking for a **built-in** solution? This could be easily solved by custom macros/functions, with or without the aid of Vim plugins.

Comment: @mMontu, I used to subscribe to all sorts of custom functionality: Web browser behavior, text editor shortcuts, window manager behavior, you name it. Every time I switched environments I would reimplement these home brewed solutions by doing a dance with configuration files, Bash scripts and other customization tools. After many years of this, I realized it is far better to become an expert with stock tools available in every environment than custom shims I put in myself to handle unique issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a macro or a mapping? Here's what I whipped up:

```
nnoremap <leader>u {j<C-v>}k^ldgvVJ0i//<esc>
```

Think of leader+u as "(U)format". Of course, you can choose different keys if you like.

Here's how it works:

```
{j<C-v>                    "Start a visual block at the top of the paragraph
       }k^l                "Move to the end of the paragraph, to select all the '//'
           d               "Delete it
            gvV            "Reselect the whole paragraph
               J           "And join it
                0i//<esc>  "Add a comment back in.
```

This is essentially the same process as you described, but easier and faster. Best part of this method? It's faster *and* builtin. =)